# Installing Kali Linux not working

Tags: installation, kali-linux

I'm trying to install kali linux on my pc. I bought dvd-rw discs and burned the AMD x64 ISO on it.

But when I select UEFI:mydvddrive there is just black screen and my DVD drive is running. I waited 30 minutes but it didn't change anything.

So I tried to install ubuntu. I did the same steps like I did on kali and it worked.

Doesn't make sense to me.

Does anyone of you guys know what I could possibly been doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Verify the secure boot from your BIOS setting , must be off , Are you dualbooting with others OS?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, beware of installing Kali Linux on a Hard Drive with the intention of using it as productive system. Kali Linux is not meant to be run 24/7 and comes with root enabled, no security whatsoever and basically not meant to be anything else then a live-system.

To your question, Kali Linux does not support UEFI out of the box. Check this link to prepare your DVD: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux